# Change Nav Class on Click from Button in Angular 2

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-components

I have a main navigation component in my angular 2 app that once an item in the nav is clicked, the selected css class is applied to the selected navigation item.  The thing that's hanging me up though is on one of the pages in my app, I have a button that once clicked routes the user to another page, and I want the main navigation to change accordingly.

Here are some snippets of my code:

**nav.component**

```
export class NavComponent {
    links: {};
    selectedClass: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.links = [
        {
            title: "Home",
            route: "/app/home",
            hidden: false
        },
        {
            title: "Add",
            route: "/app/add",
            hidden: false
        }];
    }

    selectedLink(link: String) {
        this.selectedClass = link;
    }
```

**nav.html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let link of links">
    <li *ngIf="!link.hidden" [routerLink]="link.route" [class.selected]="link == selectedClass" (click)="selectedLink(link)" [title]="link.name">
        <span>{{link.name}}</span>
    </li>
</ng-container>
```

**nav.scss**

```
li {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
  color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.selected {
    background-color: white;
    color: blue;
}
```

I want to trigger the "selectedClass" function to make the selected nav item change CSS class from a button click in another component.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at redux. You can store/modify the classname in a central location and access from anywhere in your app.

Answer (score 0):

As garethb said, you could use ngrx to have a single store where the state of the application in stored. But to keep it simple here are a couple of other ways:

You can either use `@Input() selectedClass: string;` in your `NavComponent` and pass the selected class from other components with

```
<nav-component selectedClass="class-name"></nav-component>
```

or, probably easier, is to store the selected class in an app-wide service, so a service that is for example imported in your `app.module.ts` so you know it will be a singleton.

So, in your `something.service.ts` you'll have

```
selectedClass: string;
```

and then from your component you'll set it accordingly

```
constructor(public somethingService: SomethingService) {
   this.somethingService.selectedClass = 'first-class'
}
```

and from the template you'll eventually call it with

```
somethingService.selectedClass
```